# Should I use akka.http.scaladsl.util.FastFuture instead of scala.concurrent.Future?

Tags: scala, concurrency, akka, reactive-programming, akka-http

Should I use akka.http.scaladsl.util.FastFuture instead of scala.concurrent.Future?

The comment says :

```
/**
 * Provides alternative implementations of the basic transformation operations defined on [[scala.concurrent.Future]],
 * which try to avoid scheduling to an [[scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext]] if possible, i.e. if the given future
 * value is already present.
 */
```

Do I get any performance improvement especially when I need to use
`Future.apply`, `Future.successful` or `Future.failed`?

What exactly is the difference between the two implementations?

Comment: The difference is that when you start from a `FastFuture` and call one of the  combinator methods like `map`, `filter`, etc and the underlying `Future` has already been completed, the combinator call will be executed directly on the callers stack.

Comment: You could say an already completed Future behaves then very similar to a `Try`. For a still pending `Future`, it is the same as for the regular `Future`: all combinator calls will be executed using the implicitly passed `ExecutedContext`.

Comment: Why aren't those changes just merged into `scala.concurrent.Future`?

Comment: @Jasper-M Because they break the semantics. See https://blog.ometer.com/2011/07/24/callbacks-synchronous-and-asynchronous/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially `FastFuture` allows to bypass the `Future`'s submission to an `ExecutionContext` in case the future is already completed (either successfully or not).

So in short, yes, it can give you performance improvements. Whether those will be negligible or substantial, it depends on the application you are developing.

I believe there was a plan to make these improvements part of Scala 2.12, but I never heard of those being concretised.