# What is the use of FastFuture in akka

Tags: scala, akka, future

What is the use of [Fastfuture](https://doc.akka.io/japi/akka/2.4.3/akka/http/scaladsl/util/FastFuture.html) in akka, not clear from the documentation:

> Provides alternative implementations of the basic transformation operations defined on Future, which try to avoid scheduling to an ExecutionContext if possible, i.e. if the given future value is already present.

How is it different from Future, Can someone explain with an example in what cases this to be used and what benefit does it provide in terms of performance or any other aspects?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should I use akka.http.scaladsl.util.FastFuture instead of scala.concurrent.Future?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42808593/should-i-use-akka-http-scaladsl-util-fastfuture-instead-of-scala-concurrent-futu)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When an `ExecutionContext` is used in `map` calls, that involves extra scheduling cost in scala `Future`s, while with akka `FastFuture`s it can perform map in the same thread avoiding potential context switch and potentially causing cache misses for very short tasks (like simple number crunching). So for fast `map` operations `FastFuture` should be faster.

Please note that `flatMap` usually requires an `ExecutionContext` in `FastFuture`s too as it should use that for scheduling the generated `Future`s.

It might worth checking [Viktor Klang's blog](http://viktorklang.com/blog/) and the [discussion related Futures on Scala contributors page](https://contributors.scala-lang.org/t/upates-to-scala-concurrent-future-wrt-breaking-changes/1281).

Comment: That's exactly correct. We usually use it when we "know" that a future is already completed for example. Viktor is also working on Future improve their performance significantly in the mean time, not sure on timeline though :)